# Spring Boot JPA CrudRepository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm working with Spring Boot + Spring Data JPA and facing this problem when trying to inject a class that extends CrudRepository:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'topicRepository': Could not resolve
>   matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for
>   simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)

Repository Class:

```
public interface TopicRepository extends CrudRepository<Topic, Integer> {}
```

Service Class:

```
@Service
public class TopicService {

      @Autowired
      private TopicRepository topicRepository;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: do you have `@Repository` annotation on your interface? If yes remove it.

Comment: no i don't have the @Repository annotation on the interface, the classes look exactly like in this post. Thank you.

Comment: normally this should be enough. Do you have a non default constructor on Topic Service or any other xml configuration?

Comment: i don't have xml configuration at all and for the TopicService there is only the default constructor.Thank you.

Comment: Can you provides us with your jpa configuration? Provided you have a custom jpa configuration. Thank you

Comment: I have no custom jpa configuration. Thank you

Comment: I see. My next question has to do with the packages that your classes reside. In which package resides your Application class (then one with the @SpringBootApplication annotation) and in which package resides your repository. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show your pom xml. Maybe you insert not the right dependency

Answer (score 10):

I was having the same issue, and I fixed it by switching Spring Boot versions. Changing the Spring Data JPA versions did nothing (this is where I assumed the bug would be), so I think there is a bug in Spring Boot version 1.5.1. I switched back to version 1.4.3 and the error was gone. I didn't try subsequent/different versions, so you may just have to experiment with your dependencies and their versions.

For the record, you can have your service class annotated with `@Repository`, it shouldn't make any difference. I've been setting these apps up the same way using the service/dao pattern, and it has never been too picky with the annotations. Hopefully this may help others whose Spring Boot development flow suddenly throws an error!

Answer (score 7):

Which versions of spring-data-commons and spring-data-jpa are you using. I just ran into this using spring-data-commons 1.13.x with spring-data-jpa 1.10.x. Upgrading spring-data-jpa to 1.11.x fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks for working this out already with the version combinations. It helped.

Comment: Thank you so much...spent 3 hours on this! You rock!

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same issue after updating Spring Boot to 1.5.4.

I am also using `spring-data-envers`, which was at version 1.0.4. Upgrading to 1.4.1 solved the problem.

I hope it helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure:

1) TopicRepository is annotated with `@Repository`.

2) You have the scanning packages configured:

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="mypkg.repositories"></jpa:repositories>
```

Comment: both is not necessary to do.

Comment: Spring data scans for repositories that extend CrudRepository, JPARepository etc. The @Repository annotation for spring data in not needed.

Comment: According to the Sprign spec https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/, you should add that configuration with JavaConfig - @EnableJpaRepositories or with xml as i specified

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on 1.5.2. Upgrading to 1.5.5 solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Applicationcontext to inject repository to this reference  topicRepository..
You just declare applicationcontext in @rest controller class 
Same like topicRepository by using annotation. Then you pass this to the service class which should take parms through constructor.
 Ex-
`public TopicService(Applicationcontext ctx) {this.topicRepository =context.getBean(TopicRepository.class);
}`