# Hibernate error in Spring boot initialized JPA application

Tags: spring-boot

I use spring boot 1.5.8 to initialize a web application with JPA, however, it doesn't allow me to start the application. It shows the hibernate error. It is supposed the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` will install related dependencies but it seems not:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException
...
...
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
```

Following is my dependencies in pom.xml:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: `class org.hibernate.HibernateException` should be present in `hibernate-core`, try checking your maven dependencies if it is there, if yes. Delete `~/.m2/reopsitory` and maven>update your project. It should renew your dependencies if those are corrupted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is the Version 1.5.8 has problem. Using the other versions of Spring boot initializer. I do not need to add or delete any dependency, and it works now:

change to

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Comment: very nice solution. I had the same problem and switched at version 1.5.7 and there were no problems too.

Comment: I am using a company parent so this wasn't an option, however this solution solved my problem on a related post. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43328124/2023810

Answer (score 3):

you didn't add one more dependency

```
<Dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId> <version>3.6.3.Final</version> </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot one dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>C.X.X.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

where `X` is the version of Hibernate.

Now you need to remove this dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Spring Boot will automatically try to create an entity factory for JPA, but you do not have defined anything regarding JPA models.

Comment: Now it has another error: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!`. I suppose the spring initializer should set up everything.

Comment: I definitely need the JPA

Answer (score 0):

Delete your local repository then run Maven Update Project. It should be ok.
Because your maven dependency was conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `springBootVersion = '1.5.8.RELEASE'`

I can find the `org.hibernate.HibernateException` class in `hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final-sources.jar`